# Why might the POST requests stop working?

Tags: python-requests

I've been using *requests* for years in an app that makes a post request to the state education department, which returns a web page with a list of colleges names. The requests stopped working about a week ago. Now, I'm still getting back a status code of 200, but the HTML is a web page with the message "Please page back and check your input, must select a search option" where I used to get a select element with the list of colleges as options.

I can't figure out what's changed. The website still works as expected if I use a browser to submit the form that I'm trying to mimic. My code hasn't changed, the requests library hasn't changed, my version of Python hasn't changed, and the website seems not to have changed in any overt way. So I thought perhaps the site had changed something in how it is managing the POST request. In particular, I've been looking at request/response headers to see if I could find anything there. Until now I have been letting *requests* supply the headers, but I looked at the ones that Firefox uses to make a successful request (User-Agent, Accept, etc.) and had *requests* use those. All the combinations I've tried give me the same "Please page back ..." message. (Except if I used the Host header: that returns a 404 status code.)

Here's the failing code that always exits with the message `nys_institutions.py: ERROR: received 0 institutions from https://www.nysed.gov/coms/rp090/IRPSL1/ (expected 400+).`

```
url = 'https://www.nysed.gov/coms/rp090/IRPSL1/'
response = requests.post(url, data={'Searches': "1"})
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
  html_document = document_fromstring(response.content)
  option_elements = [option.text_content() for option in html_document.cssselect('option')]
  if len(option_elements) < 400:
    exit(f'{script_file}: ERROR: received {len(option_elements)} institutions from {url} '
         f'(expected 400+).')
else:
  exit(f'{script_file}: ERROR: {url} returned {response.status_code} status')
```

Any suggestions for locating the source of the problem?